# how to sort files by the value of a dictionary using python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
    file=sorted(file)
```

the dictionary data(name, score avg) is collected earlier and stored in the file. this code then re opens the file and stores the data from it in a variable(file). I need this data from the file to be sorted by value so if the data in the file is:
james: 5
tim: 8
it will sort so that tim goes at the top as he has a higher scoreavg. How would i go about doing this?
also the dictionary is there so that name and score stay together when sorted

Comment: if you want to sort your file ascending  or descending so whats need to dictionary ?

Comment: no not ascending or decending, it needs to sort by key. I use the dictionary to keep name and score avg together. When i used a list all the data got muddled up

Comment: Python's OrderedDict may be of use. Look at the examples: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict (see the example about creating an OD from a dict by sorting by value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the data file looks like

```
tim: ["4.0", "2.9", "3.4"]
james: ["3.8", "3.8"]
clara: ["2.6", "3.5", "3.2"]
```

in which case you need something like

```
from ast import literal_eval

def sort_key(line):
    # split "name: scores" into ["name", " scores"]
    name, score_str = line.split(":")

    # convert " [\"1.9\", \"3.8\"]" into ["1.9", "3.8"]
    scores = literal_eval(score_str.strip())

    # convert ["1.9", "3.8"] into [1.9, 3.8]
    scores = [float(f) for f in scores]

    # calculate average score
    avg = sum(scores) / len(scores)
    return avg
```

then you can

```
# read data from file
with open("classa2.txt") as inf:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in inf]

# sort highest scores first
lines.sort(key=sort_key, reverse=True)

print("\n".join(lines))
```

which results in

```
james: ["3.8", "3.8"]
tim: ["4.0", "2.9", "3.4"]
clara: ["2.6", "3.5", "3.2"]
```

Comment: i really apologise but i updated the question as i worded it wrong, can you please now help as the question was slightly changed

Comment: this throws this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/James/Documents/python work/working/task 3 possible.py", line 28, in <module>
    lines.sort(key=sort_key, reverse=True)  # sort highest scores first
  File "C:/Users/James/Documents/python work/working/task 3 possible.py", line 22, in sort_key
    return int(score)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: " ['4.0']"

Comment: Apparently your file lines look not like `tim: 5` but like `tim: ['4.0']`. Adjust `sort_key` accordingly.

Comment: ok, but im a beginner, could you please edit the code in your answer so it does this, you are correct about the data. Btw thankyou for your work

Comment: please @hughbothwell, it would be really helpful to a beginner like me if you could edit this so it works

Comment: why are you working out the average even though it is stored in the data dict as score avg2

Comment: (shrug) why do another pass across the data to build the dict, when you can do it all in one go?

Comment: this code now results in this error "need more than 1 value to unpack" which i assumed was the amount of data in the file but there is 4 entries and still this error

Comment: I assume it is referring to the line `name, score_str = line.split(":")` and it means you have a line in your input file which does not contain a `:`, therefore it does not split into two pieces, therefore there is no second value to assign to `score_str`, hence the error message.

Answer (score 1):

```python
import collections

dict = {}

# Assume file format is "name:score" for each line.
with open("classa2.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(':')
        dict[line[0]] = line[1]

# Sort by value (score)
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

# Write new results
with open("classa2.txt", "w") as f:
    for key in od:
        f.write(key + ':' + str(od[key]) + "\n")
        print key + ":" + str(od[key])
```

Comment: thanks for this info but u havnt even involved the data in the file which is what i need to sort. i think i have explained this wrong. Data is being stored in the file. I then need to open the file, get the data from it and sort it, then print it to the screen. Sorry

Comment: Your question made it sound like you already loaded the dictionary, "the dictionary data(name, score avg) is collected earlier in the code in question"

Comment: 1 sec i will change the question so it makes more sense

Comment: I think I've made changes to my answer that does what you want

Comment: you code gives the error list index is out of range for the lines bit. My file has several entries

Comment: use `line = line.split(':')` instead of `line = line.split(',')`

Comment: ok no error now but it doesnt print the scores, sorted to the screen for the user to see, how would i do this

Comment: You're not just copy pasting the entire thing, are you? Make sure you apply Loupi's suggestion.

Comment: Actually, how about you just post the format of your original file?